# How to use distinct and aggregate together in single query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My MongoDB document is as follow

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622126001b68d9136e48ba4a"),
    "brand_name" : "Sony",
    "brand_rating" : [
        {
            "cust_name" : "Amit K",
            "rating" : 4
        },
        {
            "cust_name" : "Raghu",
            "rating" : 4
        }
    ],
    "models" : [
        {
            "model_name" : "Sony Xperia Z2",
            "RAM" : "3GB",
            "ROM" : "32GB",
            "price" : 18000,
            "buyer" : [
                {
                    "cust_name" : "Amit K",
                    "rating" : 5
                },
                {
                    "cust_name" : "Raghu",
                    "rating" : 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "model_name" : "Sony XP",
            "RAM" : "4GB",
            "ROM" : "64GB",
            "price" : 25000,
            "buyer" : [
                {
                    "cust_name" : "Amit K",
                    "rating" : 5
                },
                {
                    "cust_name" : "Raghu",
                    "rating" : 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I try following two queries :

```
> db.brand.distinct("brand_name")
```

Output : [ "Sony", "Samsung", "iPhone" ]

```
db.brand.aggregate({$addFields : {total_rating : {$sum : "$brand_rating.rating"} }}, {$sort : {total_rating : -1}}, {$limit : 1 }, {$project : {_id : 0, brand_name : 1, total_rating : 1} })
```

Output : { "brand_name" : "iPhone", "total_rating" : 10 }

I want to get both outputs in a single query
(Desired Output)

> [ "Sony", "Samsung", "iPhone" ] { "brand_name" : "iPhone",
> "total_rating" : 10 }

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Just curious, does `{$sum : "$brand_rating.rating"}` have any analytic value?

Comment: {$sum : "$brand_rating.rating"} is just sum of numeric values ie rating.

Comment: You can combine two (or more) aggregation pipelines using `"$facet"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rickhg12hs pointed out, you can use $facet to get something like:

```
{
"brand_set": [
  "Sony"
],
"top_sum": {
  "brand_name": "Sony",
  "total_rating": 8
}
```

}

see playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/84NadbPpDbe